# Pebble Display Cell Service

Tags: pebble-sdk

Is there a way to display the cell service bars of an iOS device on the pebble watch? I'm new to development and am wondering if this is not yet possible or I just don't know how. I haven't been able to find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Pebble API for getting this information. You would need to write a iOS companion app* to get this information from the phone and then use [PebbleKit iOS](http://localhost:4002/guides/mobile-apps/ios/) to send the data to the watch.

* Assuming there's an API for it in the iPhone SDK.